# Titanium SDK don't show devices or simulators

Tags: visual-studio-code, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Good morning,

I'm using Titanium SDK with Visual Studio Code.

But for some reason that I don't know what it is, my visual studio is always with the message "Fetching environment information", and does not disappear. [image]

Likewise, it keeps trying to load the simulators or devices, but it never goes beyond that.

[image]

Titanium version: 6.1.1
node version: 20.2.0
npm version: 9.6.7

How can I solve this problem? With that, I stopped being able to test my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will run some checks at the beginning. One potential issue could be your node version.

Support for node 20 is not official included (the latest SDK was tested up to node 19). So depending on your Ti SDK version the best node version to use is 16. That way you can use it with older SDKs and the latest SDK. If you just use Ti 12.1.x you can use node 18 (current LTS). Node 20 should theoretically work too but it will show a warning or might break (still untested).

Try `ti info -o json` to see if that works without any error or if you can build an app using the CLI.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the node version. I downgraded it to 16 and now it works